# Get disk space and separate this with most used space but put in one list

Tags: perl, bash, awk, grep, sh

Want to get disk space and separate this with most used space but put in one list

Example how get the used space:

```
df -P | grep -vE 'Filesystem' | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }'
```

Output:

```
89% /
1% /oralog
24% /oradata
0% /dev/shm
```

Expected view:

```
[bad] 89% /
[ok] 1% /oralog
[ok]24% /oradata
[ok]0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Is that part of your input, or do you want to calculate it?

Comment: Note: the `-E` with `grep` is for extended regular expressions. You aren't using any features from ERE, in fact you are searching for a fixed string so you would want `-F`. However you don't need `grep` here as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drop the `grep` by skipping over the first line in `awk` with `NR>1` as the condition for the block. Just set the value of `x` to be the limit for good/bad, in the example I set the limit as 80:

```
$ df -P | awk 'NR>1{print ($5>x)?"[bad]":"[okay]",$5,$6}' OFS='\t' x=80
[bad]   89%    /
[ok]    1%     /oralog
[ok]    24%    /oradata
[ok]    0%     /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
awk '{if($5>20) a="[bad]"; else a="[good]";} {print a, $5 " " $6}'
```

All together:

```
$ df -P | grep -vE 'Filesystem' | awk '{if($5>20) a="[bad]"; else a="[good]";} {print a, $5 " " $6}'
```

Test (whith threshold of 20%):

```
$ df -P | grep -vE 'Filesystem' | awk '{if($5>20) a="[bad]"; else a="[good]";} {print a, $5 " " $6}'
[bad] 25% /
[good] 1% /dev
[good] 1% /run
[good] 0% /run/lock
[good] 1% /run/shm
[good] 1% /run/user
```

Answer (score 1):

Only disk with highest usage has `[bad]`

```
df -P | perl -anE '$F[4]=~s/%//||next;push@r,[@F];$m<$F[4] and $m=$F[4];END{say $m==$$_[4]?"[bad]":"[ok]"," $$_[4]% $$_[5]"for@r}'
```

output

```
[ok] 44% /
[ok] 0% /lib/init/rw
[ok] 1% /dev
[ok] 0% /dev/shm
[bad] 61% /ftp
```